# Cron tab scheduling for different timings on different days

Tags: cron, airflow

I need to schedule a job from Mon-Thur at 7pm and on Friday i need it to be scheduled at 11pm. I am using Airflow and need the cron tab notation like

**0 19 * * Mon-Thu**

Any suggestion are welcome.

Thank you

Regards,
CJ

Answer (score 0):

You can create your dag as:

```
dag = DAG("Your_dag", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="0 19 * * 1-4")
```

Comment: that is for mon-thur but i need it to run at 11 on friday. how do i accommodate that ?

Comment: I guess you should handle it as two different DAG.another dag for 11 pm Friday.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```py
schedules = {
    'M-Th': '0 19 * * 1-4',
    'F': '0 23 * * 5',
}

for name, schedule in schedules.items():
    globals()[name] = DAG('<base_dag_name.' + name, default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=schedule)
```

This will create two DAGs from a single file. DAGs need to be in the global scope to be recognized by Airflow.